# Using Echo on terminal

Tags: unix

I want to show at least two uppercase words files name but they aren't side by side

I used it..

```
echo ![*[A-Z][A-Z]*]
```

but it is not true using

Comment: What is your *expected* output?

Answer (score 0):

[echo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) displays *values*

To display *file*(-name)s, use [ls](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)

Other than this, it is unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: For example file names are not so : ..AA.. they must be so : AdAm

Comment: How about `ls *A*A*`?  If this solves your problem, I'll update the answer with explanation.  Otherwise you will need to provide some filenames that fulfill your citeria and ones that you do not want included so we can better understand what you are looking for

Comment: Actually echo displays whatever you pass it, which program do you think is translating the glob pattern to filenames? Hint: it's not `ls`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "glob pattern", but AFAIK if you want to get information (such as name) about files, echo won't help.  Once you get the information in textual format (possibly stored in a variable), you can use echo to output it, possibly in a modified way.

Answer (score 0):

My understandind of the question is: List any filename with at least two uppercase letters, not necessarily adjacent to each other but anywhere in the name.

For example:

```
cAdgfgfZfdsfgdf 
d456FJsfd
ABC
```

`echo` is to print the given string, it'll not search files as you expect it here.

This will do:

```
 $   ls -l | grep "[A-Z]"*"[A-Z]"
```